# Download a file with password and username with C#

Tags: c#, download

How would I write a script to download files from this site. Is it possible to supply the login and password with the url?

http://feeds.itunes.apple.com/feeds/epf/

Would I format the url like this?

```
WebClient Client = new WebClient();
Client.DownloadFile("http://feeds.itunes.apple.com/feeds/epf/v3/full/current/itunes20110511.tbz.md5?username=myusername&password=mypassword", @"C:\folder\file.md5");
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, just set the `WebClient's` [`Credentials` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.credentials.aspx) to a [`NetworkCredentials`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential.aspx) instance with the username/password. For example:

```
Client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("john", "password1234!");
```

Answer (score 18):

Use [WebClient.Credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.credentials.aspx) property to supply your credentials to the web site:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
    client.DownloadFile("http://feeds.itunes.apple.com/feeds/epf/v3/full/current/itunes20110511.tbz.md5", @"C:\folder\file.md5");
}
```

Comment: Not working for me It is still displayed login page content in HTML

Comment: @MSTdev Posting to a wrong question? This page does not *have* a login page. It uses RFC2617 authentication and when you are not logged in sends back status 401 with WWW-Authenticate  header. You are probably trying to solve a problem that has no relevance to this question or answer.

Comment: Not working for me too. It displaying 400 error(Bad Request). Please help me.... The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.